# Can't save phylogenetic tree to pdf with color

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, ape-phylo

I am trying to save my phylogenetic tree with coloured branches using discrete data, everytime I do the pdf() function and then try to open it I get a pdf error. 
This is the code I am using

```
tree = read.nexus("phylo.1966")
tree3<-read.csv("BBS1966.2015.pgls.csv",row.names = 1)
tree3<-setNames(tree3[,1],rownames(Nesting))
cols<-setNames(palette()[1:6],levels(Nesting))
Nesttree<-make.simmap(drop.tip(tree2, setdiff(tree2$tip.label,names(Nesting))),Nesting, model = "SYM"
plotTree(Nesttree,cols,type="fan",fsize=0.8,lwd=3,ftype="i")
add.simmap.ledgend(colors=cols,x=0.9*par()$usr[1],y=0.9*par()$usr[4],prompt=FALSE,fsize=0.9)
pdf("Nesting1.pdf", width = 100, height = 100)
dev.off()
```

however, if I place the pdf function before the plotTree function it will open but no color is added to the tree.
tree2 is from a code used previously which just took my original tree and added the subspecies to make a new tree.

Also if I try to manually save the plot as a jpeg the size of the tree remains the same but the plot area will change to the size I chose, so it looks small and super crowded.

Thank you for any help.
[This is the image I produce after using the corrected code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTn8H.jpg)

Comment: You can manually adjust you image size `?jpeg`. Use `width` and `height`. You code wouldn't work as you open your `pdf` after drawing your plot. The order you want to do it is open device (pdf, jpeg etc), run code that draws you image, close your device (`dev.off()`)

Comment: @George your comment should be an answer, it looks like it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented you can manually adjust the width and height of images if you images is crowded. You can use any device in place of `jpeg` (e.g. PDF) for pdf however you don't need to set height or width.

```
jpeg("filename.jpeg", height = 1080, width =1080)
plotTree(Nesttree,cols,type="fan",fsize=0.8,lwd=3,ftype="i")
add.simmap.legend(colors=cols,x=0.9*par()$usr[1],y=0.9*par()$usr[4],prompt=FALSE,fsize=0.9)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the pdf and it will open but no color is present on the tree, the tree is all black. this also occurs when I try it with jpeg

Comment: @BirdNerd171 Can you provide details of where the `plotTree` function and the `add.simmap.legend` functions come from. If running just those to functions dose R draw a coloured tree?
Just noticed you have a typo (i assume) in the name of the function, in your code it is `add.simmap.ledgend` shouldn't it be `add.simmap.legend`